# how to add folder and made work in vb.net

Tags: android, vb.net

how to add folder in project

[image]

in screenshot

add test folder with include file and

cannot use test folder

eg. file.copy("test/adb.exe","C:/adb.exe")
    shell("""test/adb.exe"" reboot")

when use shell command & file copy then show (Could not find a part of the path 'test/adb.exe'.)

And how to made test folder work in project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are facing is actually quite simple. Your folder structure in your project has absolutely nothing to do with the EXE file after you compile.

When you compile your project, Visual Studio will do the compiling for you and then put WindowsApplication2.exe in a bin folder (bin stands for binary which basically means "compiled"). You can compile in two different modes: debug mode and release mode. You can check these settings in project properties (right click on project name and click properties).

If you are compiling in debug mode, then your .exe file will be located in folder C:\where-ever-you-have-stored-your-project\bin\debug  or  if you are compiling in release mode C:\where-ever-you-have-stored-your-project\bin\release.

When you run your program, it tries to find your file under (let's say you compile under debug):  C:\where-ever-you-have-stored-your-project\bin\debug\test\adb.exe  <-- and this does not exist!

To fix this problem, you can actually INCLUDE YOUR FILES when you compile your project. Click on the "adb.exe" file and then change the setting of **Copy to Output directory** from "Do not copy" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" if you prefer it that way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks For answer my question.This helping me.

Change the setting of Copy to Output directory and it works 

now i can run shell command but still other problem

when i compiling project (debug mode and release mode)
 file and directory not include in project.

And how to compiling project include file and directory(folder).

Thank...

Comment: Please re-check your statement. When you compile your solution the folder Test will be created next to WindowsApplication2.exe and inside of that folder there will be adb.exe -> but you must be careful. You have to **click** on adb.exe and then select Copy to Output directory.